# How get one single component (carousel) from element-ui if is imported as global config object?

Tags: vue.js, import, carousel, element-ui

Hi in project i have included [element-ui](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/installation).

In app.js:

```
import Element from 'element-ui'
```

and after:

```
Vue.use(Element, {locale})
```

So in my single file components template i can use carousel like this: (In this component is not any initialization carousel via vue like import, parent whatever...)

```
<el-carousel>
  <el-carousel-item>
    <p>hello!</p>
  </el-carousel-item>
</el-carousel>
```

And it works... BUT. How i can access to this element? Look to actual slide, use events and so on....?

I was tried in component something like:

```
import { Carousel } from 'element-ui';
```

and add to components list... It works, but it is another instance of this class...

So how i can GET real instance of carousel from DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy. Make reference on element via [ref](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) attribute like this:

```
<el-carousel ref="myreference"></el-carousel>
```

and after this access:

```
console.log(this.$refs.myreference);
```